# com.android.support:design:23.3.0 broken when custom view used in Tablayout

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-tablayout

I am adding custom view to `tablayout` for that I am using following linked method:

```
https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout
```

this is working fine.  I am using `com.android.support:design:23.1.1`, but when I update to `com.android.support:design:23.3.0` there is a problem:

The custom view is visible but when I call

```
 viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

then the custom view is no longer visible, IT'S GONE. Any idea what has changed in 23.3.0 that can affect this?

How can I solve this issue? The same code is working properly in 23.1.1 but not in 23.3.0.

Comment: i assume its a bug

Comment: does any one facing ? or they have changed something ?

Comment: I use this.notifyDataSetChanged() in my adapter and it works I have 23.3.0

Comment: this.notifyDataSetChanged() saying cant resolved this method . u also facing same issue ? maytham ?

Comment: it works fine for me, no issues

Comment: viewPager.getAdapter() is the problem ?

Comment: where are you adding viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()? in that example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110207/discussion-between-andro-and-maytham-mahtyam).

Comment: For me `23.3.0` has wrong colors in a `NavigationView`. Downgraded to `23.2.0`..

Comment: this is present in 23.4 also

Comment: I have the same problem. Any issue recommended ?

Comment: I think i found a kind of solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37327189/802055

Comment: Look like a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39583428/444398